# Merge array if shared element, element being array

Tags: python, arrays, merge

i was wondering how can i merge arrays which share an element, the element being shared is another array.

```
def def_ladders(bridges):
    ladders = []
    i = 0
    for b1,b2 in itertools.combinations(bridges, 2):
        if is_same_ladder(b1,b2) == 1:

            ladders.append([b1,b2])
```

this produce an array of pair of array:

```
[[[7, 37, 'P'], [8, 38, 'P']],
 [[137, 200, 'P'], [138, 201, 'P']],
 [[138, 170, 'P'], [139, 171, 'P']],
 [[138, 201, 'P'], [139, 202, 'P']],
 [[230, 251, 'P'], [231, 252, 'P']]]
```

I want to merge  `[[137, 200, 'P'], [138, 201, 'P']]` with `[[138, 201, 'P'], [139, 202, 'P']]` then merge it again with another element if the new element produced share element with others.

```
Output = [[[7, 37, 'P'], [8, 38, 'P']],
          [[137, 200, 'P'], [138, 201, 'P'], [139, 202, 'P']],
          [[138, 170, 'P'], [139, 171, 'P']],
          [[138, 201, 'P'], [[230, 251, 'P'], [231, 252, 'P']]]
```

But i want the program to check if  `[[137, 200, 'P'], [138, 201, 'P'], [139, 202, 'P']]` share element with other arrays and so on if a new sub(array) is generated

So it's try to merge `[[137, 200, 'P'], [138, 201, 'P'], [139, 202, 'P']]` which is created with all other sub(array) like `[[138, 170, 'P'], [139, 171, 'P']]`, in this case it's wont merge cause they don't share sub(array)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: plz clarify " then merge it again with another element if the new element produced share element with others."

Comment: I want the program to check if new sub(array) creating by merging shared element with all others sub(array). I want to be able to generate sub(array) of length n and not only length 3, sorry if i'm unclear.

Comment: You want to combine sub-array if it has an overlapping sub-sub-array?

Comment: No i just want my program to try to combined newly created sub(array):